# Dependency injection for WCF where client uses ChannelFactory

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, channelfactory

I have a scenario where I need to inject a type from a WCF, `ChannelFactory` instantiation.

Currently, I am using http://unitywcf.codeplex.com/, and understand the underlying concepts but do not see an example there on **how I can instantiate a service client using Channel factory that injects the type I want to pass onto the WCF constructor.**

I am open to other approaches other than the UnityWcf library.

I hope I am making sense.

I've spent pretty much of the whole day trying to figure it out.

**Update:**

The only option I have so far, is to add the interface as a parameter in each WCF operation.

Comment: can you provide some code so we can better understand the problem here

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Castle project. They have a IoC container called Windsor which has very great WCF integration.

http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor/

Comment: Thanks @Pieter. I am well aware of Castle and I have looked into it. I need an answer on HOW to do it for my specific scenario. Can you provide an  answer relating to my question?

Comment: Can you provide me with a small peace of sample code? I don't exactly understand what you want to accomplish.